# what's the different between UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged and touchesMoved?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm investigate dragging `UIView` after `LongPressGesture`.Some code using `touchesMoved:`, some code check `UIGestureRecognizerStateChange`. I still not understand, which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html):

> When a gesture recognizer recognizes a discrete gesture, it sets the state property to UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized. If the gesture is continuous, it sets the state property first to UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan; then, for each change in position of the gesture, it sets (or resets) the property to UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged. When the gesture ends, it sets state to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded. If at any point a gesture recognizer realizes that this multitouch sequence is not its gesture, it sets its state to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed.

So if the user touches the screen always generates a touchedMoved event, and if it's in the middle of a continuous gesture it also causes the UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged state to be set.

Comment: Thanks! I have a problem when dragging UIView.When use touchesMoved:,it move all Views.But when check LongPress gesture UIGestureRegconizerStateChange, it go to StateEnd when apply removeFromSuperView and addSubView. Any suggestion?

Comment: Long press doesn't "change"...it only starts and ends...what would the "change" be?

Comment: Long press state: start - change - end. I've test successful, but it can't go to change state when removeFromSupperView.